# A program to copy a file to another file is successful but after copying letter 'y' got print infinitely

Tags: c

I want to copy contents of one file to another file. 
 After execution of the code, the desired output gets printed but a additional letter 'y' gets printed in the 2nd file and 'y' falls into infinite loop.

Another thing is 2nd printf is also not getting input, whether I add file path to minimize the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char ch, filename1, filename2;

    printf("enter file name to open:\n");
    scanf("%c", &filename1);

    fp1 = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot open targeted file");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("enter another file name to open:\n");
    scanf("%c", &filename2);

    fp2 = fopen("testfile2.txt", "w");
    if(fp2 == NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot open targeted file");
        fclose(fp1);
        exit(2);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp1);
        fputc(ch, fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's ÿ that's printed, isn't it?  That's LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS in Unicode, aka U+00FF, or y-umlaut.  It's what you get when you don't detect EOF correctly.  The `getchar()`, `getc()` and `fgetc()` functions return an `int`, not a `char`.  And you don't try to detect EOF.  You need `int ch; while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) fputc(ch, fp2);`.

Answer (score 5):

Your copying loop doesn't attempt to detect EOF.  It should read:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    fputc(ch, fp);
```

Note that the value is read into an `int`, not a `char`.  The `getchar()`, `getc()` and `fgetc()` functions return an `int`, which either contains a positive number representing the character (byte) treated as an `unsigned char`, or it returns the negative value `EOF` (which is customarily, but not necessarily, `-1`).  You can't store all those values in a `char`; you must use an `int`.

It's also a little peculiar to ask your user to enter a file name and then ignore what they enter.  In most ways, it is just as well you do; you need more than a single `char filename1` or `char filename2` to hold a file name, and you need to use `%s` rather than `%c` to read the names.  Fortunately, you use fixed string literals for the file names in the `fopen()` calls.

The reason that the second input doesn't seem to wait is that your first call to `scanf()` reads a single character, so even if you type `a` as the file name, there is also a newline in the input.  The second `scanf()` reads the newline.  There are only 3 formats that don't skip leading white space (such as newlines).  They are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.

Comment: Thanks buddy for this help, it's very encouraging and also i am doing more mistakes.